# using @Qualifier + @Bean(autowire=Autowire.BY_TYPE) in javaConfig

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have an Employee bean having Address type of dependency. I'm trying to configure autowiring in javaConfig. But getting `NoQualifyingBeanException`.
 Although I'm using `@Qualifier()` annotation as follow :

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

    @Bean(name="addr1")
    public Address address() {      
        return new Address("Hello","hi",112233);
    }

    @Bean(name="address")
    public Address addressAgain() {
        return new Address("See You","Bi",114422);
    }

    @Bean(name="emp",autowire=Autowire.BY_TYPE)
    @Qualifier("addr1")
    public Employee employee() {

        Employee e = new Employee();
        e.setName("Raghu");
        e.setEmpID(111);
        //e.setAddress(address());

        return e;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Specifying a different `name` attribute in each `@Bean` method is not enough.
You should consider marking one of the beans as `@Primary` :

```
@Primary
@Bean(name = "address")
public Address addressAgain() {
    return new Address("See You");
}
```

And leave the other(s) without :

```
@Bean(name="addr1")
public Address address() {      
    return new Address("Hello","hi", 112233);
}
```

Note that you don't need to add the `@Qualifier("addr1")` annotation in the `employee()` method to be able to autowire the `addr1` bean.
Spring already knows the `Address` bean instance you refer to as you set the dependency from a `@Bean` method : `address()`.

So it is enough :

```
@Bean(name = "emp", autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)
public Employee employee() {
    Employee e = new Employee();
    e.setName("Raghu");
    e.setAddress(address());
    return e;
}
```